# Draw dynamic graph on python

Tags: python, user-interface, graph

I am trying to draw a dynamic graph which I want to control ( moving edges or nodes, update data of edges or nodes, click on edge to show more information...).
I have tried several programs and packages like prefuse, networkx and also processing.
But with these, we cannot control edges (onClick listener for exemple) we can just control nodes.
I have also a little problem because I am using python to parse the data and binding languages is a new thing for me , I have tried Jython with processing which was really slow...
I will appreciated any help of you
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview-elasticnodes.html

You should be able to make the same using Python Binding for C++/Qt aka PyQt or Pyside. It should run and render much faster.